# How does this code work, and where is this syntax documented?

Tags: go

I found a github snippet custom unmarshaling JSON at https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/904f0fdad34eaac09c5d53098f960c5c.  It works well, but I hate using code I don't understand.

Specifically, this part uses syntax I'm not familiar with:

```
type Alias MyStruct
    aux := &struct {
        SomeCustomType int64 `json:"someCustomType"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(s),
    }
```

I understand a new type, `Alias` is being declared, and that it has the same fields as MyStruct.  `aux` is initialized as a pointer to a struct with a redefined field `SomeCustomType`.

What I've not seen before is the declaration of `Alias` within the `aux` struct - `(*Alias)(s)`.
What is this actually doing?  Where can I find the documentation on this piece of Go syntax?

Comment: It's a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), converting the value `s` to the type `*Alias`.

Comment: @EndreSimo, type assertions are something else and have the form `(x).(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

The section `{ Alias: (*Alias)(s) }` is not a declaration, it's a [struct literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

A struct literal sets the fields of a struct (in this case, an anonymous struct). Let's break it down:

The `Alias:` part is setting the [embedded field](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) of the struct. Since the struct embeds `*Alias`, it does not have a field name for it, and the type is used instead.

The `(*Alias)(s)` part is an explicit [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), changing whatever `s` is to the type `*Alias` (as long the types are compatible).